# java.lang.NullPointerException bug when trying to run an app on netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jsr296

Here is my traceback

```
Oct 9, 2012 3:58:44 PM org.jdesktop.application.Application$1 run
SEVERE: Application class sampleapp.SampeAppApp failed to launch
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sampleapp.SampeAppView.<init>(MusicDownloaderView.java:89)
        at sampleapp.SampeAppApp.startup(MusicDownloaderApp.java:18)    
at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:171)
            at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:682)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
            at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:643)
            at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:641)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:652)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Application class musicdownloader.MusicDownloaderApp failed to launch
            at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:177)
            at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:682)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
            at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:643)
            at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:641)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:652)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

also all my marked occurrences is

```
 jPanel1.removeAll();
```

Line 89 is

```
 jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
```

Any ideas how to solve this ? I also searched online to find any help but i didn't found anything. All answers are appreciated. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: obviously  jPanel1 gives null..pls check its elements!

Comment: provide these lines please:  sampleapp.SampeAppView.<init>(MusicDownloaderView.java:89)
        at sampleapp.SampeAppApp.startup(MusicDownloaderApp.java:18)

Comment: @AshokRaj how jPanel1 gives null? Could you explain it a bit more ?

Comment: the line 89 is      jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

Comment: The problem is in the constructor of `SampeAppView`.  Perhaps you could post that?

Comment: show me what's @  sampleapp.SampeAppView.<init>(MusicDownloaderView.java:89)

Comment: @DavidGrant what part of code to post of the constructor?

Comment: Just post it all.  The more context, the better.

Comment: Obviously `jButton1` is `null` at that particular moment. Check your initialisation.

Comment: how to check if is null? When i click on properties of jButton in action says null? must i remove it ?

Comment: It's really hard to advise you without any relevant source code.

Comment: i changed it from null to jButton1.action and i did not get back null on print out ...but the problem still exists

Answer (score 1):

Have you initialized jButton1?
Since the NullPointerException occurs an line 89, jButton1 is probably null.
To be sure, try simply `System.out.println(jButton1);`, if it prints out Null, it means you didn't initialize it correctly.

I don't know if it's the case, but if it is, avoid variable declarations like `JButton jButton1 = null;`, using `JButton jButton1;` instead, because by initializing a variable with null you're preventing the compiler to warn you whenever you forget to initialize an object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to DEBUG your code:

[Basic Netbeans debuging](http://www.cs.uga.edu/~shoulami/sp2009/cs1301/tutorial/NetBeansDebuggerTutorial/NetBeansDebuggerTutorial.htm)

[Debug Java Applications with Netbeans](http://manikandanmv.wordpress.com/2009/09/24/debugging-java-applications-with-netbeans/)